# Connected components of a spherical subgroup from spherical data?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, spherical-varieties

This question is in a similar spirit to [this one by Mikhail Borovoi](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250430/the-group-of-g-automorphisms-of-a-spherical-variety-from-the-spherical-datum).

Let $G$ be a reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $X=G/H$ be a homogeneous spherical variety.
Losev proved that the spherical $G$-variety $X$ is uniquely determined by its spherical datum $(M,\Sigma,\mathcal D,\rho,\varsigma)$, which I will recall below. For example, in the cited question one sees how the automorphism group of $X$ may be read off of this data.

My question regards the group of connected components $\pi_0(H)$. I am in a situation where it would be great to be able to compute this group abstractly (without knowing $H$, for example) from the datum.

> **Question.** Can one compute $\pi_0(H)$ from the spherical datum of $X$?

Frankly, partial results would be helpful (eg: can one at least detect if the component group is non-trivial?).

Let me now recall the description of the spherical datum of $X$ as stated in the above linked question:

Let $B\subset G$ be a Borel subgroup, and let $T\subset B\subset G$ be a maximal torus.
Let $S=S(G,T,B)$ denote the corresponding system of simple roots.
Let ${\mathcal{P}}(S)$ denote the set of subsets of $S$.

Let ${\mathcal{X}}(B)$ denote the character group of $B$, and let $M\subset {\mathcal{X}}(B)$ denote the weight lattice of $X$.
Set $N={\rm Hom}(M,{\mathbb{Z}})$, $N_{\mathbb{Q}}={\rm Hom}(M,{\mathbb{Q}})$.
Let $\mathcal{V}\subset N_{\mathbb{Q}}$ denote the valuation cone of $X$, and let $\Sigma\subset M$ denote  the corresponding set of spherical roots.

Let ${\mathcal{D}}$ denote the set of colors of $X$ (the set of $B$-invariant prime divisors of $X$). We have two maps:
$$\rho\colon {\mathcal{D}}\to N,\qquad \varsigma\colon {\mathcal{D}}\to {\mathcal{P}}(S). $$
Here, for $D\in{\mathcal{D}}$,
$$ \varsigma(D)=\{\alpha\in S\ | \ P_\alpha\cdot D\neq D\}, $$
where $P_\alpha\supset B$ denotes the parabolic subgroup corresponding to $\alpha\in S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H^\circ\subseteq H$ be the connected component of unity and let $M^\circ$ be weight lattice of $X^\circ:=G/H^\circ$. Since $\pi_0(H)=H/H^\circ$ acts as automorphisms on $X^\circ$ it follows that $\pi_0(H)$ is the dual group of, hence isomorphic to, the finite abelian group $M^\circ/M$. Thus, everything boils down to compute $M^\circ$. Now, this has been done by Hofscheier in his paper [Containment Relations among Spherical Subgroups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00378). Corollary 1.5 states, in particular, that $$M^\circ=\{\chi\in M_{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathcal X(B)\mid \langle\rho(\mathcal D),\chi\rangle\subseteq\mathbb Z\}.$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!